# --Why isn't the bottom border showing up here?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

> 

I don't see it, I simply changed my prvious CSS from

`border-bottom` to `borderBottom` when I started using React.

```
const style = {
  borderBottom: '3px solid black'
}

return (
  // ... snip
        <li style={style} onClick={this.clickHandler2.bind(this)} id="nav_fave">
  // ... snip
)
```

Comment: borderBottom isn't a css property, border-bottom is

Comment: Have you tried using `borderBottomWidth`, `borderBottomColor` separately.

Comment: In React, borderBottom is indeed what the css property is called.

Comment: you have a typo, `boderBottom` instead of `borderBottom`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have a typo mistake (instead of `borderBottom` it's `boderBottom` in your case.)

This code works for me

```
const style = {
  borderBottom: '3px solid black',
  borderTop: '3px solid red'
};
return (
    // ... snip
    <li style={style} onClick={this.clickHandler2.bind(this)} id="nav_fave">
    // ... snip
)
```